# MySQL в чём ошибка?

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю вывод отдельной статьи.

Файл `index.php` при нажатии на название статьи отправляет запрос в `article.php`.
Запрос:

```
<a href="article.php?id=<?=$article['id'] ?>"><?=$article['title'] ?></a>
```

`article.php` работает со скриптом. Вот, предположительно проблемная часть:

```
function article_get($link, $id_artilce) {
    $_GET['id'] = $id_article;
    $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id=$_GET'id'", (int)$id_article);
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    $article = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $article;
}
```

Ошибка:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id'' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Для начала поправить синтаксис [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php)

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id=%d", (int)$id_article);
```

И нужно поменять местами `$_GET['id']` и `$id_article`, если Вы хотите в переменную `$id_article` занести значение из массива `$_GET`:

```
$id_article = $_GET['id'];
```

И аргумент `$id_artilce` функции `article_get()` не используется в теле функции.